# How disable second disk on laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu on SSD (first) disk and also HDD (second, instead DVD-ROM) disk on my laptop. The second disc I use rarely. When my laptop is turned on, it does not emit any sound, but HDD peeps because it work. How I can disable HDD, but turn on if necessary? I.E. to run kubuntu with disabled HDD, but enable it, if necessary.

Comment: If you don't mount it, then it isn't being used.  Did you configure it to be automatically mounted somewhere when you installed?  If not, then it should have an icon you can open, but if you never open it ( or if you have, then right click the icon and eject/unmount it ) and then it isn't being used.

Comment: @psusi disk automatically mounted with run Kubuntu, but I don't mount.

Answer (score 1):

Would like to add that I found the Disks Utility (Disks in the Ubuntu Applications launcher) quite handy. You can select the standby options for the HDD by going into Drive settings in More actions.

[image]

Comment: I there found item "Enable now", it will serve. But I can't enable HDD schedule

Answer (score 0):

You can set how many seconds of idleness the hard drive should wait before it goes to sleep with the `-S` in `hdparm`

`hdparm -S 128 /dev/sdb`

From the hdpram manual

> ```
>    -S     Put  the  drive  into  idle  (low-power) mode, and also set the standby (spindown) timeout for the drive.
>           This timeout value is used by the drive to determine how long to wait  (with  no  disk  activity)  before
>           turning  off the spindle motor to save power.  Under such circumstances, the drive may take as long as 30
>           seconds to respond to a subsequent disk access, though most drives are much quicker.  The encoding of the
>           timeout  value  is somewhat peculiar.  A value of zero means "timeouts are disabled": the device will not
>           automatically enter standby mode.  Values from 1 to 240 specify multiples of 5 seconds, yielding timeouts
>           from  5 seconds to 20 minutes.  Values from 241 to 251 specify from 1 to 11 units of 30 minutes, yielding
>           timeouts from 30 minutes to 5.5 hours.  A value of 252 signifies a timeout of 21 minutes. A value of  253
>           sets  a  vendor-defined  timeout  period  between  8 and 12 hours, and the value 254 is reserved.  255 is
>           interpreted as 21 minutes plus 15 seconds.  Note that some older drives may have very different interpre‐
>           tations of these values.
> ```

To send the hard drive to sleep immediately, enter:

`hdparm -y /dev/sdb`

> ```
>  -y     Force  an  IDE  drive  to immediately enter the low power consumption standby mode, usually causing it to
>           spin down.  The current power mode status can be checked using the -C option.
> ```

With an upper case `Y`, the drive will go into an even deeper state of sleep.

```
   -Y     Force an IDE drive to immediately enter the lowest power consumption sleep mode, causing it to shut  down
          completely.   A  hard  or  soft  reset  is required before the drive can be accessed again (the Linux IDE
          driver will automatically handle issuing a reset if/when needed).  The current power mode status  can  be
          checked using the -C option.
```

Drives are supposed to spin up when they get a command that requires reading the disk.  This must be supported by the BIOS and the drive itself.

When you are satisfied with your options you can make it automatic by inserting the command, *above the last line*, into `/etc/rc.local` with your favourite text edit as superuser.